# An object changes to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

The Context of the Example:
The example consists firstly of displaying the list of groups for each role in a datatable expansion
Then, display the list of users assigned to each group and check the users benefiting from the role. (This part is functional)

The problem I want to remove the assignment of a role to a user and to be done I used this code,

```
 <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
                    listener="#{roleMB.deleteAffectationRU(rl,ut)}"
                    update=":rightForm:roleDataTable:dataGroupe:dataUtilisateur    :rightForm:formAjout:message" 
    process="@this"/>
```

The role parameter rl passes  but the user parameter ut passes null

XHTML

```
 <p:dataTable id="roleDataTable" var="rl" value="#{roleMB.roles} rowKey="#{rl.id}selection="#{roleMB.selectedRoles}">
          <p:column style="width:16px">
          <p:rowToggler /></p:column>
          <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
          <p:column headerText="Designation">
             <h:outputText value="#{rl.designation}" /></p:column>
          <p:rowExpansion>
            <p:dataTable id="dataGroupe" value="#{rl.affectationsRG}" var="document">
               <p:column style="width:16px">
               <p:rowToggler /></p:column>
               <p:column headerText="Designation">
                  <h:outputText value="#{document.groupe.designation}" /></p:column>
               <p:ajax event="rowToggle"
                       listener="#{roleMB.listerUtilisateur(rl,document.groupe)}"
                       update=":rightForm:roleDataTable:dataGroupe:dataUtilisateur" 
                       process="@this"/>
              <p:rowExpansion>
                 <p:dataTable id="dataUtilisateur" 
                              value="#{roleMB.utilisateursGroupe}" var="ut"                                 selection="#{roleMB.selectedUtilisateurs}" rowKey="#{ut.id}">
                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-  align:center" />
                <p:column headerText="login">
                   <h:outputText value="#{ut.login}" /></p:column>
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
                        listener="#{roleMB.deleteAffectationRU(rl,ut)}"
                        update=":rightForm:roleDataTable:dataGroupe:dataUtilisateur    :rightForm:formAjout:message" 
        process="@this"/>
        </p:dataTable>
        </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
```

managedBean

```
public void deleteAffectationRU(Role rl,Utilisateur ut ){
        System.out.println("Role "+rl.getDesignation());
        System.out.println("User "+ut);
    roleService.deleteRoleUser(ut.getId(), rl.getId());
    Message.constructInforMessage("role deleted ");
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does `#{ut.login}` resolve to a value? Have you double-checked that `roleMB.getUtilisateursGroupe()` returns the expected collection of users?

Comment: Yes login and utilisateurGroupe  Are displayed correctly

Comment: The first line misses one `"` (but I doubt that this causes the trouble)

Comment: That's not the problem

Answer (score 1):

The listener method implementations on the backing bean will receive the event. As far as I understood after looking at the documentation,

```
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
        listener="#{roleMB.deleteAffectationRU}"
        update=":rightForm:roleDataTable:dataGroupe:dataUtilisateur :rightForm:formAjout:message" 
        process="@this"/>
```

should be handled by a method

```
public void deleteAffectationRU(UnselectEvent event) {
   // implementation
}
```

So we can't pass custom values - the listeners are always event handlers.

I hope it helps to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I want to pass the parameters of role and utilisateur to 'deleteAffectationRU',

Comment: I know... but it may not be possible this way. Unless you find a way to attach them to the event.